# Model Builder not showing feature layer FID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

In the middle of a routine I'm making on model builder I have a generate near table function beetween two feature of points. The results give me a table with only the coordinates of the points and their FIDs of every combination. From these coordinates I make lines using the XY to line and keep all the FIDs on this new shapefile.

What I want to do is use the join field function to recover all the information in the attribute table form both points of each line using the FID from both tables (line feature and point feature) as the common attribute. However the model builder doesn't recognize that there is a FID field on the points attribute table. If I do the whole routine myself without model builder it works, but on model builder I can't work around it.

Anyway I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe switch from Shapefile to Geodatabase featureclass, key on Objectid for your join.